# WPF : Is it possible for me to bind to the SelectedValue of a combo box?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I've a data table in which a list of user information is being kept.

To simply interact with that table I've created a class which takes the User ID (The Primary Key of the table), and queries the table to retrieve user information :

```
public class User {
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new User Object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ID">User UUID</param>
    public User( string ID ) {
        this.UserID = ID;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get User UUID
    /// </summary>
    public string UserID { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set User Name
    /// </summary>
    public string UserName {
        get { return this.Get( "User_Name" ); }
        set { this.Set( "User_Name", value ); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set User Company
    /// </summary>
    public string UserCompany {
        get { return this.Get( "User_Company" ); }
        set { this.Set( "User_Company", value ); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set User Email
    /// </summary>
    public string UserEmail {
        get { return this.Get( "User_Email" ); }
        set { this.Set( "User_Email", value ); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set User Phone Number
    /// </summary>
    public string UserPhone {
        get { return this.Get( "User_Phone" ); }
        set { this.Set( "User_Phone", value ); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get string representation of this User.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>User Name</returns>
    public override string ToString( ) { return this.UserName; }

    private string Get( string fromField ) {
        return RegistrationTables.UsersTable == null ? "USER TABLE EMPTY" :
            RegistrationEntries.Get<string>( RegistrationTables.UsersTable, "User_ID", this.UserID, fromField );
    }

    private void Set( string toField, string value ) {
        if ( RegistrationTables.UsersTable == null )
            return;
        RegistrationEntries.Set( RegistrationTables.UsersTable, "User_ID", this.UserID, toField, value );
    }
}
```

Now I also have a ComboBox, the datasource of which I am setting to a list of users :

```
this.cbxUsers.SetBinding( ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding( ) { Source = RegistrationTables.GetUsers( this.SystemID ) } );

public static List<RegistrationEntries.User> GetUsers( string SystemID ) {
        return RegistrationTables.SystemUsersTable == null ? null :
            RegistrationTables.SystemUsersTable.AsEnumerable(
            ).Where( Row => Row.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted && Row.Field<string>( "Computer_ID" ) == SystemID
            ).Select( ( Row ) => new RegistrationEntries.User( Row.Field<string>( "User_ID" ) )
            ).OrderBy( User => User.UserName ).ToList( );
}
```

Within the control containing this combobox I have a series of text boxes, which display the user information. The manner in which it is currently being done has not yet been tested, but I know it will work :

```
this.cbxUsers.SelectionChanged += ( cbxS, cbxE ) => {
    RegistrationEntries.User User = ( cbxS as ComboBox ).SelectedValue as RegistrationEntries.User;
    this.tbxBuyerName.Text = User.UserName;
    this.tbxBuyerEmail.Text = User.UserPhone;
    this.tbxBuyerPhone.Text = User.UserPhone;
    this.tbxBuyerCompany.Text = User.UserCompany;
};
```

However, what would be ideal is for me to be able to implement some method of two-way binding each text box to the different properties of the `SelectedValue` of the ComboBox which contains the users such that each time a new user is selected from the combobox, then the text boxes will be populated with the relevant values, and each time one of the text boxes is changed, then the user will have their respective value updated.

Is this possible? Is this even reasonable? If not, is there some simpler alternative which I've overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to contain your Users and the CurrentUser like this:

```
public class UsersViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private User _currentUser = null;

    public UsersViewModel(IEnumerable<User> users)
    {
        this.Users = new ObservableCollection<User>(users);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return this._currentUser;
        }

        set
        {
            this._currentUser = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentUser");
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<User> Users { get; protected set; }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Create some Xaml that looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ComboBox Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentUser, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="UserName" />

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">UserName</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUser.UserName, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Email</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUser.UserEmail, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">Phone</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Path=CurrentUser.UserPhone, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then set the DataContext of your Window or UserControl to a instance of UsersViewModel.

Comment: I should mention I've been working with XAML and WPF for like... a week. Maybe two. Do you have some example code or a URL to tell me how to do that?